# How to make canvas background transparent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am playing around with a pen, and I can't seem to figure out how to make the background of the canvas transparent.

I am trying to change the background from black to transparent :

http://codepen.io/netzzwerg/pen/gzuIb

I think it's in here but nothing i've done seems to work

```
  clear: function() {
        //context.fillStyle = this.c;
        context.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0, 0.1)";

        context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255, 1)';
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
  clear: function() {
        //context.fillStyle = this.c;
        context.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        context.fillStyle="rgba(0, 0, 200, 0)";
        context.fill();

        context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255, 1)';
    }
};
```

Set the fillstyle to an alpha - and then call .fill (which I think is basically what you were doing anyway?)